# how to Post encrypted data from http page to https page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, http, encryption, https

We have a site which was not using SSL and SSL just have been introduced into it. We are implementing SSL just on login page but site was providing two places to login 1) login page and 2) a login widget on home page.We don't want home page to be using https and SSL.

There need to pass user id and password from Home Page Login widget to back end in encrypted format.

Please guide how it can be done ? Can it be done if somehow I put https: in action url and/ or make form method post ? Using Ajax or any other method please ?

Kindly advice me how it can be done ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried using an https action url? What were the results of your experiments?

Comment: cjc343 thanks, I tried both but in my all tries it was un encrypted. Any advice please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply changing the action URL to `https://` should be enough.

Comment: Be aware, however, that this is not secure.  A man-in-the-middle can intercept your unencrypted page, and change the url to their data collection site and steal your users passwords.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau thanks, are you sure about it ? I mean have you implemented this or it is just your perception ? Can you please also guide how it can be tested (mean encrypted data) ?